# How to test packet loss and recovery features of Secure Reliable Transport Protocol

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, streaming, h.264, srt

I am using h264 encode method with ffmpeg and I am able to stream it with UDP Protocol. Without packet loss video quality is good. Since UDP Protocol does not guarantee packet reliability , I implemented Haivision's Secure Reliable Transport (SRT) protocol on top of UDP Protocol.

Before that I tested UDP Protocol with dropping some percentage of packets intentionally by writing simple program and video stream results were not that good.Since I am using h264 , losing packets effects video quality rapidly. Now I am using SRT Protocol on top of UDP Protocol. SRT Protocol also use UDP Protocol but it has packet recovery feature for live video streams. I want to test it's packet drop recovery feature and see the results.

How can i do that programmatically or with any tools?

[SRT Protocol Repository](https://github.com/Haivision/srt)

Comment: It's not clear enough what would you like to test: SRT's packet recovery or the impact of the video quality.